# I have this error and I don't know what to do

Tags: python

```
def Reset():
        data = []
        data.append({
            'year': now.year,
            'months': []
        })
        for year in range(len(data)):
            for month in range(12):
                data[year].months.append({
                    'month': (month + 1),
                    'days': []
                })
                if (month+1 == 2):
                    daysAmount = 28
                    if (isinstance(year/4, int)):
                        daysAmount = 29
                elif (month+1 == 12):
                    daysAmount = 31
                elif (isinstance((month+1)/2, int)):
                    daysAmount = 30
                else:
                    daysAmount = 31
                for day in range(daysAmount):
                    data[year].months[month].days.append({
                        'day': (day + 1),
                    })
        with open('./data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
    
    
    
    Reset()
```

I changed the code, but now another error came I don't understand. What should I do about this one? As you can see it does have an attribute months...

```
line 13, in Reset
    data[year].months.append({
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'months'
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that `len(data)` is a number, not something you can iterate over. Did you mean `for year in data`?

Comment: use `for _ in range(len(var)):`

Comment: Please don't edit your question to completely remove the original question itself and ask a new/followup question. (I see that you also asked the answerer for clarification in comments, and got it sorted it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to get the number of items in the data list instead of the actual objects into the 'year' variable and for that you should use

```
for year in range(len(data)):
```

as follows

```
import json
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()

def Reset():
    data = []
    data.append({
        'year': now.year,
        'months': []
    })
    for year in range(len(data)):
        for month in range(12):
            data[year]['months'].append({
                'month': (month + 1),
                'days': []
            })
            if (month+1 == 2):
                daysAmount = 28
                if (isinstance(year/4, int)):
                    daysAmount = 29
            elif (month+1 == 12):
                daysAmount = 31
            elif (isinstance((month+1)/2, int)):
                daysAmount = 30
            else:
                daysAmount = 31
            for day in range(daysAmount):
                data[year]['months'][month].days.append({
                    'day': (day + 1),
                })
    with open('./data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)



Reset()
```

The other way would be to use

```
for year in data:
```

as follows

```
import json
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()

def Reset():
    data = []
    data.append({
        'year': now.year,
        'months': []
    })
    for year in data:
        for month in range(12):
            year['months'].append({
                'month': (month + 1),
                'days': []
            })
            if (month+1 == 2):
                daysAmount = 28
                if (isinstance(year/4, int)):
                    daysAmount = 29
            elif (month+1 == 12):
                daysAmount = 31
            elif (isinstance((month+1)/2, int)):
                daysAmount = 30
            else:
                daysAmount = 31
            for day in range(daysAmount):
                year['months'][month].days.append({
                    'day': (day + 1),
                })
    with open('./data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)

Reset()
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error see post above thisone.

Comment: Yes but I need the upper example because further in the code I need the year variable as a number for some math equations. The first one errors though. i changed main question.

Comment: Got it. Python Dicts are not the same as JavaScript Dicts. We need to access months as `data[year]['months']` and not as `data[year].months`.

Comment: Just a sec. Editing

Comment: Made those changes!

Comment: Done! ty again!

Comment: It was Fun! Thank You so much!

Answer (score 1):

The len() function does return an integer .

```
for x in y:
```

y here must be a list or something iterative not an integer

by using `len(data)` your just returning the length of list

you should use

```
for year in data:
```

Answer (score 0):

when u do len(data), it returns an integer which is not iterable;

hence you should do something like:

```
for year in range(len(data))
```

or

```
for item in data.item:
     year = item['year'] 
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you of this line

```
for year in len(data):
```

This len(data) returns integer and that is not iterable.

Instead you can do this

```
for item in data:
    year = item['year']
```

or

```
for index in range(len(data)):
    item = data[index]
```

Comment: This is what I needed Thanks!